# C: Ask user to enter a string. Write a function that takes the string as a parameter, encrypt the message as described above and returns ciphertext

Tags: c

I am currently working on an assignment and I thought I completed it but my while loop is in a constant infinite loop and I don't know where I'm messing up. I have tried getting help but TA's are not a big help. If you could take a look it would be greatly appreciated.
. . 
. .
. . 
. . 
. .
. .
. . 
. .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define Max_Length 100
#define Max_String 100

    char* encrypt_message (char* message, int length) //Encrypted Message function
    {
        char *cipher;
        char array_1 [(Max_Length + 1) / 2];
        char array_2 [(Max_Length + 1) / 2];
        int k = 0, i;
        int l = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < Max_Length; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 1)
            {
                array_1[k] = message[i];
                k++;
            }
            else
            {
                array_2[l] = message[i];
                l++;
            }
        }
        cipher = strcat (array_1, array_2);
        cipher[Max_Length] = '\0';
        return cipher;
    }

    int main()
    {
        char plain_text[Max_String][Max_Length];
        char cipher_text[Max_String][Max_Length];
        int str_len, i, j;
        char *temp;
        char choice = 'N';
        int l = 0;
        do
        {
            char * str;
            printf("Please enter a message: ");
            gets(plain_text[l]);
            str_len = strlen(plain_text[l]);
            str = encrypt_message(plain_text[l], str_len);
            strcpy(cipher_text[l], str);
            printf("The encrypted message is: %s\n", cipher_text[l]);
            printf("Do you want to continue (Y/N)? : ");
            scanf("%c", &choice);
            l++;
        }
        while (choice == 'Y' || choice == 'y'); //Something is messing up (Constant While Loop)
        {
            printf("\n\n The original message in alphabetical order are\n");
            for (i = 0; i < l; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < l - 1; j++)
                {
                    if (strcmp(plain_text[j], plain_text[j + 1]) > 0)
                    {
                        strcpy(temp, plain_text[j]);
                        strcpy(plain_text[j], plain_text[j + 1]);
                        strcpy(plain_text[j + 1], temp);
                    }
                }
            }
            for (i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                printf("%s\n", plain_text[i]);
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's very confusing that you have a block (`{...}`) underneath a `do{...}while` loop.

Comment: what did you see when you stepped through with the debugger?

Comment: Add `getchar();` after `scanf("%c", &choice);`. Does that resolve your problem?

Comment: It gives me no errors when I compile the program.

Comment: @FiddlingBits maybe explain why that fixed it

Comment: @pm100 See answer.

Comment: the function: `gets()` has been depreciated for years and completely removed from modern C language standards.  Your compiler should have told you that.

Comment: regarding; `char *temp;` and `strcpy(temp, plain_text[j]);`  the pointer `temp` is never set to point to any memory owned by the application.  This results in undefined behavior.  Therefore, anything could happen.  Always enable the warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.  For `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`  Note: other compilers take different options to produce the same results

Comment: regarding: `gets(plain_text[l]);`  the `gets()` function does not stop inputting characters until the user enters a '\n' Therefore, it will (easily) overrun the available array entry length for each entry.  The result is undefined behavior, so anything can happen.  STRONGLY suggest using `fgets()`

Comment: regarding your statement: *It gives me no errors when I compile the program.*   Either you have not enabled the warnings when compiling or you need to obtain a new/modern compiler.  `gcc` is a free modern compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add `getchar` after `scanf("%c", &choice);`, your problem will be resolved.

The problem you were having was caused by a newline being left in the input stream.  After entering a `y` and pressing enter (and assuming nothing else) a newline character is left in the input stream; when `gets` is called on the next iteration, the newline character is consumed setting `plain_text` to "\n".

This can be observed when you enter more than one character:

```
$ ./main.exe
Please enter a message: hello
The encrypted message is: elhlo
Do you want to continue (Y/N)? : yes please
Please enter a message: The encrypted message is: spese lae
Do you want to continue (Y/N)? :
```

To resolve the issue observed above, add another loop to consume all characters after the first until a newline is found:

```
scanf("%c", &choice);
while(getchar() != '\n')
    continue;
```

Now observe the results:

```
$ gcc main.c -o main.exe; ./main.exe;
Please enter a message: hello
The encrypted message is: elhlo
Do you want to continue (Y/N)? : yes please
Please enter a message:
```

**Note**

`gets` should not be used.  Use `fgets` instead because it prevents buffer overflow.